# Imap Simple - Get replied mail content only

Tags: javascript, imap

Sorry for my poor english, I'm doing my best! I'm working on a Node project on which I want to be able to get emails from an inbox. Actually, it worked fine, perhaps there is only one detail on which I'm having some troubles.

I want to be able to dissociate answered mail content from the initial e-mail, but imap is giving me the full thread in html, text or textAsHtml.

Here's the code :

```
var imaps = require('imap-simple');
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;
const _ = require('lodash');

.
.
.
.
.

fetchMails() {
        var config = {
            imap: {
                user: 'catchall@foobar.fr',
                password: 'foobar',
                host: 'imap.gmail.com',
                port: 993,
                tls: true,
                authTimeout: 3000
            }
        };
        
        imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
        
            return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
                var searchCriteria = [
                    'UNSEEN'
                ];
        
                var fetchOptions = {
                    bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT', ''],
                    markSeen: false,
                };

                return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (results) {

                    results.forEach(r => {
                        var all = _.find(r.parts, { "which": "" })
                        var id = r.attributes.uid;
                        var idHeader = "Imap-Id: "+id+"\r\n";

                        simpleParser(idHeader+all.body, async (err, mail) => {
                            console.log(mail.textAsHtml);
                            } else {
                                console.log('nothing for now');   
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

And it show me this for example :

```
textAsHtml: '<p>Here is the reply !<br/>Foo Bar -</p><p>Le sam. 7 d&eacute;c. 2019 &agrave; 18:36, &lt;<a href="mailto:catchall@foobar.fr">catchall@foobar.fr</a>&gt; a &eacute;crit :</p><p>&gt; Here is the initial mail<br/>&gt;</p>',
```

Does anyone have any idea on how i could proceed to get only the reply ?
Or maybe getting an array of all (top) contained `<p>` in `textAsHtml` ?
Thanks btw! Happy coding.